# How to disable Emoji Keyboard in iPhone iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard, emoji

I enabled Emoji Keyboard in an iOS 5.0 device by using this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"KeyboardEmojiEverywhere"];
[dict writeToFile:PREFS_FILE atomically:NO];
```

It worked great, and I was able to see an option for Emoji keyboard in the Settings ->General -> Keyboard -> International keyboards ->Add New Keyboard

But now, I want to remove the Emoji keyboard from International Keyboards list, as it was before. For this, I did:

```
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"KeyboardEmojiEverywhere"];
```

But the Emoji Keyboard is still visible, I am not able to get it to disappear.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *remove* the key, you set it to NO:

```
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"KeyboardEmojiEverywhere"];
[dict writeToFile:PREFS_FILE atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Set the key to NO, then restarted the iPhone, still it gives an option to choose the Emoji keyboard. Is it that the Emoji keyboard is provided by Apple by default in iOS 5 and above? This thing works fine in iOS 4.3. In fact removing the key worked in pre iOS 5.

Comment: iOS 5 has a standard emoji keyboard.  You can't get rid of it.  That's a why it only works in iOS 4.x

Comment: Yes I just saw that this morning. Emoji is already enabled in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your iPhone after removing from Application. You can also install `Emoji keyboard` from Appstore, the delete it, restart. You will get `Emoji keyboard` removed.

Comment: No luck :( I restarted the iPhone, still it shows the Emoji Keyboard option.